# Distributed IMAP-Dictionary-Attack-Tool?

Tags: brute-force, imap

I have a client with a hacked IMAP-Account, and the attacker(s) made thousands of password-attempts, probably with a fixed set of passwords, from different IPs before they got in.

After successful password guessing I see 10-15 different IPs connecting and pushing out spams, simply killing that little ol' post-fix server :(. After flushing 440.000 mails from the queue and resetting all passwords to secure ones, Nr 5 lives, again!

My question:

- What tool is used for distributed attacks on accounts / spam sending? i know about hydra & consorts, but I never saw a tool for botnet-like brute force. Are sources  available somewhere?

Edit: changed brute-force to dictionary attack

Comment: Assuming you already have a botnet this doesn't seem like such a difficult attack to create. An actual brute-force would obviously be a bit trickier than just a dictionary or rainbow-tables, are you sure they really did a true brute force? Or do you only have hashes?

Comment: dictionary attack.

Answer (score -1):

This might give you a little in-site into the process needed to perform this type of thing, http://du.nham.ca/blog/posts/2013/03/08/password-cracking-on-amazon-ec2/  it uses http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/ along with ec2 to perform circa 2320.9 million MD5 hashes per second, it's maybe not exactly what you looking for but it will certainly give you some pointers.

Comment: You refer to offline password cracking, which has nothing to do with the question.